# How to sort a query result by their date (Jpa, Java Collections)

Tags: java, jpa, collections

```
public List<Movie> findRange(int[] range) {
    CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(Movie.class));
    Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    List<Movie> list1 = q.getResultList();
    Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator(){
           public int compare (Object o1, Object o2){
               Movie p1 = (Movie)o1;
               Movie p2 = (Movie)o2;
               return p2.getDate().compareTo(p1.getDate());
           }
       });
    return list1;
}
```

As it is now sorting works, but only with in the batch, 
(batch = 4 movies) First one = last entered; Last one = fisrt entered. 
But only compared with those in the batch not all of them as needed.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide 
best Regards
Ignacio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably define the order in the criteria query and not sort the results after the query has already been executed. Otherwise you will end up sorting only a part of the results.

You can assign sort order to the query using [CriteriaQuery.orderBy(Order ...)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#orderBy%28javax.persistence.criteria.Order...%29). The order by expression can be created with the CriteriaBuilder using either [asc(Expression)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#asc%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) for ascending or [desc(Expression)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#desc%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) for descending order.

The following might or might not work:

```
public List<Movie> findRange(int[] range) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Movie> cq = cb.createQuery(Movie.class);
    Root<Movie> movie = cq.from(Movie.class);
    cq.select(movie);
    cq.order(cb.asc(movie.get(Movie_.getDate()));


    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but It does not work, why is it that you already know it might not work? what can I change to make it work?

Comment: Well, I guessed it might not worked because I didn't test it. I would think that either the compiler or the JPA engine might log some messages that a hint of what's going wrong. The JEE 6 tutorial contains a bit about ordering results in JPA 2:  http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjiwo

Comment: It worked!!!! thank you very much just needed a set it correctly, just one question. Why cq.order(cb.asc(movie.get(Movie_.getDate())) and not as previously cq.orderBy(cb.asc(movies.get("date")));?

Comment: Perhaps the string based API called needed an explicit cast to prevent the date being compared as a Path. Using `movie.<Date>get("date")` might work better. Using the metamodel is more straightforward in this case.